# Iterator in functional programming

Tags: c++, functional-programming, iterator

Is it possible to implement an iterator in C++ with an algebraic data type. Suppose I have a tuple which contains a bunch of elements of type T. Would it be a good idea to use variant as an iterator to go through the tuple? What would be the best way in a functional programming manner to iterate over a tuple.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please take some time to read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of your own attempt together with a description of the problems you have with it.

Comment: I find functional programming to work best in a programming language designed to be a functional programming language, like F#, OCaml, Haskell, or Elm.  (Probably Clojure too... but I haven't used that one, so I've no personal experience with it.)

Answer (score 2):

Functional programming-style iteration over a tuple would probably look something like this:

```
template <typename Tuple, typename F, size_t... Is>
void IterateHelper(const Tuple& t, F f, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
  (f(std::get<Is>(t)), ...);
}

template <typename Tuple, typename F>
void iterate(const Tuple& t, F f) {
  IterateHelper(t, f, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<Tuple>>{});
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Pc6fK6)

Comment: There is `std::apply`: `std::apply([f](auto&&... args){ (f(args), ...); }, t);`.